# Random Crash using Google Maps with Markers updation

Tags: ios, iphone, gmsmapview

I am using xcode version 6.1 for development.
My application is getting crashed on iPhones (iOS 7 & iOS 8) but not on iPods (iOS 8).
The application uses Google Maps to show Markers of different users which gets updated dynamically. When the application goes in sleep mode, it crashes next time I unlock the phone.

```
    Incident Identifier: 251C80CC-6B39-4B1D-9196-EA494DC3FCDB
    CrashReporter Key:   4fcaa62262030543fdc423f96e35d8e41a9998c9
    Hardware Model:      iPhone3,2
    Process:         Application [310]
    Path:            (null)
    Identifier:      com.mapmymeet.mobulous
    Version:         1.0.4 (1.0.4)
    Code Type:       ARM
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2015-03-20 19:58:39.000 +0530
    OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  0 (SIGPIPE)
    Exception Codes: 0x00000000 at 0x3894aa58
    Crashed Thread:  0

    Binary Images:
       0xc3000 -   0x782fff  Application armv7  <63fa1d54012d36cc817840177e80d93b> /var/mobile/Applications/3F62D047-D357-4424-823A-850903BD4F03/Application.app/Application
    0x2e71e000 - 0x2e748fff  GLKit armv7  <5aec7f0e85f23b1f82e76f048fb172ac> /System/Library/Frameworks/GLKit.framework/GLKit
    0x2f369000 - 0x2f414fff  MessageUI armv7  <7b327d4e306c3808af0a6a1ee5dae3ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI
    0x2d34d000 - 0x2d35efff  AssetsLibrary armv7  <bd32e25ad0063147ae26a6c154243793> /System/Library/Frameworks/AssetsLibrary.framework/AssetsLibrary
    0x2ca96000 - 0x2cb98fff  AVFoundation armv7  <2bb988ba37473ce087d10d9a50f47327> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
    0x2e956000 - 0x2eb66fff  ImageIO armv7  <68e088d928123efabf846c5d9cdb7fea> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
    0x303d7000 - 0x30426fff  SystemConfiguration armv7  <3b71117feef432fc81b0fa5fade30fa4> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
    0x3863c000 - 0x386d2fff  libsqlite3.dylib armv7  <74e96bf0e7463b71a151bd580edc8aee> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
    0x30427000 - 0x30428fff  Twitter armv7  <cef81f3a27b8318aa76b33d284332c3a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
    0x2d1ac000 - 0x2d1ccfff  Accounts armv7  <e58ce4873fe23f91b70bbb907deaf71f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
    0x30288000 - 0x302fffff  Social armv7  <df458b398cdb3c4996744aa801ded77c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social
    0x2d1cd000 - 0x2d1cdfff  AdSupport armv7  <3b665e5a345235d7bd2cc47bf84973e8> /System/Library/Frameworks/AdSupport.framework/AdSupport
    0x2d94e000 - 0x2db42fff  CoreData armv7  <694f017c380c36e79d8372e4b8800b1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
    0x30429000 - 0x30b9cfff  UIKit armv7  <be4762f112843dc6a4d91f15c0e5d17a> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
    0x2dc86000 - 0x2dda9fff  CoreGraphics armv7  <011601c0f5613306846b94a7c8c841da> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
    0x2e532000 - 0x2e71dfff  Foundation armv7  <8b34e834206d3d75b8c0ba6acbee7280> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
    0x2ee65000 - 0x2f062fff  MediaPlayer armv7  <01755f42ccd2340cbea0ca55652cc0df> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
    0x38821000 - 0x3882dfff  libz.1.dylib armv7  <76b41c58034a30dabe6ad9be1e637644> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
    0x37bf0000 - 0x37c3bfff  libc++.1.dylib armv7  <a9e17626396330e4be0a636d853ecded> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
    0x2e2d1000 - 0x2e361fff  CoreText armv7  <a4ce222c044833b1baf58246c277a013> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
    0x38397000 - 0x38536fff  libobjc.A.dylib armv7  <bf96d212244538e3a0c9fa3b779326c2> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
    0x379ec000 - 0x379edfff  libSystem.B.dylib armv7  <89c8b9badf4e3d5594391736841b2f25> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
    0x2cbc2000 - 0x2cbc2fff  Accelerate armv7  <0424978b39f037a7b3bf9aad5b34a5b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
    0x2d1ce000 - 0x2d235fff  AddressBook armv7  <c742d15daada36238f237d74bcfb7f0e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
    0x2d236000 - 0x2d34cfff  AddressBookUI armv7  <50ef2d12c0c130f9a9d033c55cfcee26> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBookUI.framework/AddressBookUI
    0x2db43000 - 0x2dc85fff  CoreFoundation armv7  <4f5fe18d15f2330bb4759690b5d2e575> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
    0x2dff2000 - 0x2e0cbfff  CoreImage armv7  <4d57e424137a39a2b4ff192f4ceb6d9f> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
    0x2e0cc000 - 0x2e11bfff  CoreLocation armv7  <1a32fefcfcac3237aa4ea5fab2b85120> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
    0x2e153000 - 0x2e1cefff  CoreMedia armv7  <b83a60988a8d3c6abed3e40706cd6228> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
    0x2e278000 - 0x2e2d0fff  CoreTelephony armv7  <9e2ae41b084135baba20bc14a0eb938c> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
    0x2edb0000 - 0x2ee5ffff  MapKit armv7  <98e19767bef2383395eadc86ec3d7128> /System/Library/Frameworks/MapKit.framework/MapKit
    0x2f415000 - 0x2f478fff  MobileCoreServices armv7  <69108a456cf33dfcbd558b14687b1b6a> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
    0x2feb3000 - 0x2febbfff  OpenGLES armv7  <093444e2377c3bdaa89101c44c93da7a> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
    0x300a5000 - 0x301ebfff  QuartzCore armv7  <a746a2753fee36e9b5f2c7b341b4b940> 
 /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
    0x38848000 - 0x38880fff  libcorecrypto.dylib armv7  <912e56f196943500877e1aba46efcb78> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
    0x38881000 - 0x388a5fff  libdispatch.dylib armv7  <ffb7ebb4a206398fbf7507e05e6b7b96> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
    0x388a6000 - 0x388a7fff  libdyld.dylib armv7  <e3df65531c733096b90b3187b7894592> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
    0x388a8000 - 0x388a8fff  libkeymgr.dylib armv7  <a671e49149e7326dafa58332efdb4bd0> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
    0x388a9000 - 0x388affff  liblaunch.dylib armv7  <1efc4b3c146d347cb586fce80e8acdcb> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
    0x388b0000 - 0x388b3fff  libmacho.dylib armv7  <0ffeb9459e8d3ba99467a159b8c23d78> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
    0x388b4000 - 0x388b5fff  libremovefile.dylib armv7  <ab36d6cb22b833e9bce2c2c375f57cea> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
    0x388b6000 - 0x388c3fff  libsystem_asl.dylib armv7  <6569ced4c68b3a119b89f3a8f48564be> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
    0x388c4000 - 0x388c4fff  libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7  <0178b6f1a9bf362d9672641076a42ee2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
    0x388c5000 - 0x38926fff  libsystem_c.dylib armv7  <371f0e1854f03b05ba143619e4eac99f> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
    0x38927000 - 0x38929fff  libsystem_configuration.dylib armv7  <3e82bcb352f53951b5bce186bf9c30f7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib
    0x3892a000 - 0x38930fff  libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7  <b80a9e53918437fba1e1db7ba356a378> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
    0x38931000 - 0x38949fff  libsystem_info.dylib armv7  <2996bfe2d4833c20b428a1b7b4db3c52> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
    0x3894a000 - 0x38962fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7  <b40caaf7c97c33aa8748dabfe96b86de> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x38963000 - 0x38982fff  libsystem_m.dylib armv7  <e048061f381f312f821e46076636e2ec> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib
    0x38983000 - 0x38994fff  libsystem_malloc.dylib armv7  <d9a0e50b10803815952b52e50988ae91> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
    0x38995000 - 0x389b5fff  libsystem_network.dylib armv7  <ef504a73980e3df7b637b0e3e2663489> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
    0x389b6000 - 0x389bdfff  libsystem_notify.dylib armv7  <932b71a166a3302f92405c0e77031b11> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
    0x389be000 - 0x389c3fff  libsystem_platform.dylib armv7  <12ec95161bda391c8db84f7255b85501> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
    0x389c4000 - 0x389c9fff  libsystem_pthread.dylib armv7  <bdb1cf2e67983b65b5bd694b3cde3dc0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
    0x389ca000 - 0x389cbfff  libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7  <a4289fa3fcb03507bcc49b3ea68b6e86> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
    0x389cc000 - 0x389cefff  libsystem_stats.dylib armv7  <0f72cd8b79ad3600b2eb01c4391b2f53> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_stats.dylib
    0x389cf000 - 0x389cffff  libunwind.dylib armv7  <45c29718368e3d1c8821911ab5953080> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
    0x389d0000 - 0x389eafff  libxpc.dylib armv7  <399deef84c9e3570a39520230faa3216> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
    0x37bd9000 - 0x37be5fff  libbsm.0.dylib armv7  <cbf50b2cb2ae3ff385d5d853551a33cf> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
    0x2cbcc000 - 0x2cd98fff  vImage armv7  <c4834965bdc638fcb1082f53a7721f42> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
    0x2d1ab000 - 0x2d1abfff  vecLib armv7  <7b2718a5a22c36e6ab943b2e4bea9123> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
    0x2d12a000 - 0x2d198fff  libvDSP.dylib armv7  <174c13fd605a39efbb7f1314a6d1fdbe> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
    0x386d3000 - 0x38720fff  libstdc++.6.dylib armv7  <60d2a9f34296398bb7c057e01fde6afc> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
    0x2ce73000 - 0x2d129fff  libLAPACK.dylib armv7  <65970a4fea383446b0b4b87e634b8dfd> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x2cd99000 - 0x2ce72fff  libBLAS.dylib armv7  <cfc693306499378c9c09851259cf3563> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
    0x2d199000 - 0x2d1aafff  libvMisc.dylib armv7  <5a8317adbade34a9b415e44ab8c64eb6> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
    0x3874b000 - 0x387fefff  libxml2.2.dylib armv7  <610d9be70005338f9db94dbcaf1b6459> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
    0x2d7bb000 - 0x2d8d9fff  CFNetwork armv7  <32c4f521ed6338bf96139f76cf3f609e> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
    0x3798d000 - 0x379a3fff  libCRFSuite.dylib armv7  <f9dee1c7149a3f29a26328ddfe0536eb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
    0x3800d000 - 0x3800dfff  liblangid.dylib armv7  <8bb499713b5632adb09d7bb3a7b77a71> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
    0x379b9000 - 0x379cefff  libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7  <e32cf2e0d70d3df7b459c46a1e952bd8> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
    0x2fec6000 - 0x2fecdfff  libGFXShared.dylib armv7  <fe98d6ca3e423f9e93aa993bd407fa7e> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
    0x32e72000 - 0x32e79fff  IOMobileFramebuffer armv7  <3eec4ccff3193502b6316f3439ab3afd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
    0x2fece000 - 0x2ff0cfff  libGLImage.dylib armv7  <1e247052e47436548415ab280cc11c79> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
    0x2febd000 - 0x2febdfff  libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7  <4160c7889e203462bdfe31aa45fd9169> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
    0x2fec2000 - 0x2fec5fff  libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7  <e1f32d8903623237a187c0bd063efe59> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
    0x31e1f000 - 0x31e20fff  CoreSurface armv7  <99788346c24335a9841971c2f59456e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
    0x3577d000 - 0x3583dfff  UIFoundation armv7  <9eb899e4a11e3692aaa25553bb8ba25d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
    0x3800e000 - 0x38018fff  liblockdown.dylib armv7  <5c6bed6567d8332baeba16b0b9fa325d> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
    0x332bb000 - 0x332c5fff  MobileKeyBag armv7  <61151535a91d3ea2974ea6a06166747e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
    0x31ec7000 - 0x31f23fff  CoreUI armv7  <2223abab101d3f5b95810c26f00baec7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUI.framework/CoreUI
    0x2e362000 - 0x2e371fff  CoreVideo armv7  <490d0406923830dfaa7ec16a3bb82187> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
    0x30b9d000 - 0x30beafff  VideoToolbox armv7  <4ccd9c8d42ac3682ac1650c169b55cef> /System/Library/Frameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
    0x33264000 - 0x33270fff  MobileAsset armv7  <78bd6fbf778f3c4f9ec2313ec5186d08> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileAsset.framework/MobileAsset
    0x3511a000 - 0x3513bfff  TelephonyUtilities armv7  <e10dd172382138069cd1f0848c4f40eb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TelephonyUtilities.framework/TelephonyUtilities
    0x3175d000 - 0x31782fff  BackBoardServices armv7  <e61d4b244f1a39ccaa1abaa96badcea8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BackBoardServices.framework/BackBoardServices
    0x369ab000 - 0x369b3fff  XPCObjects armv7  <278385b224443259bcda55693ace3bcd> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/XPCObjects.framework/XPCObjects
    0x321a6000 - 0x321c0fff  DictionaryServices armv7  <76bd0946ffd9363f986b85d837589ff2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
    0x32a47000 - 0x32a5dfff  GraphicsServices armv7  <78c2c4fd5c6535cfb73da15b290270fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
    0x34c98000 - 0x34cadfff  SpringBoardServices armv7  <d4f3ee614b273bee8561f5ec7eec73ec> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
    0x315c6000 - 0x31604fff  AppSupport armv7  <78c7141f2ac93b7dbf135aa577805c38> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
    0x354c6000 - 0x354f9fff  TextInput armv7  <b1fa9668f93e391c83f8d723e456799d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
    0x367a0000 - 0x36860fff  WebKit armv7  <81b2c7768c3b3a638ad2a697cfcbf218> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
    0x35cf7000 - 0x3679ffff  WebCore armv7  <a92bef00b4113a8f827123773ba7a3a1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
    0x348c8000 - 0x3494efff  ProofReader armv7  <5127dc9d030235e6a19a786852e11617> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
    0x37789000 - 0x37790fff  libAccessibility.dylib armv7  <c566d2e701bf3e619ea4add455e374ac> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
    0x3488d000 - 0x348c4fff  PrintKit armv7  <5e906c574ea63dff8e231abb3a369504> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
    0x34763000 - 0x34796fff  PhysicsKit armv7  <38e5c1f9753d3a5daddda25fd331c15b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhysicsKit.framework/PhysicsKit
    0x31b28000 - 0x31b2afff  ConstantClasses armv7  <f58642d4aadb3b7f885e454c1721cb3a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
    0x332ed000 - 0x332f0fff  MobileSystemServices armv7  <f496c18eac07325a8987e11b4d1a2dae> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileSystemServices.framework/MobileSystemServices
    0x3178c000 - 0x317b0fff  Bom armv7  <aea46aa95cb83f79894d9baf26b3b284> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
    0x37be6000 - 0x37beffff  libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7  <3a4d64c44c283997b46efa5712f9c2d1> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
    0x33d40000 - 0x33d7bfff  OpenCL armv7  <a80f3369930237c7b2fdab58d46a52f3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
    0x32250000 - 0x3266bfff  FaceCore armv7  <d21d7f5811263d5e91736457e432a4f8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCore.framework/FaceCore
    0x35855000 - 0x35858fff  UserFS armv7  <13209e5d1fea31d9b48c9dad7871fe76> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserFS.framework/UserFS
    0x31f78000 - 0x31f7dfff  CrashReporterSupport armv7  <702819044e50369bb385f39f8a8f459e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
    0x2d8da000 - 0x2d935fff  CoreAudio armv7  <10173be0d8bc39aca273f270ec6265d8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
    0x3172e000 - 0x3173bfff  AssetsLibraryServices armv7  <b28a77e12f4a351b8da0cc3ad0254cd8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
    0x32205000 - 0x32210fff  ExFAT armv7  <e548232decfb3856afd9090fdfc72e8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ExFAT.framework/ExFAT
    0x31a86000 - 0x31a91fff  CommonUtilities armv7  <757437b86d8f31299fd1ac1c30a69cd7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
    0x37a5c000 - 0x37a8afff  libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib armv7  <79c60debf82c32e3b39e7b4b019ad981> /usr/lib/libTelephonyUtilDynamic.dylib
    0x350c4000 - 0x350c6fff  TCC armv7  <e3ca6a2109a933b8898817b14d359881> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TCC.framework/TCC
    0x31a92000 - 0x31a96fff  CommunicationsFilter armv7  <15910b7ac8c53a7f87b05f2ead994df1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommunicationsFilter.framework/CommunicationsFilter
    0x32e0e000 - 0x32e68fff  IMFoundation armv7  <f7aec8dbd9743fefb2ac8dbe7f722c5e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMFoundation.framework/IMFoundation
    0x38721000 - 0x38747fff  libtidy.A.dylib armv7  <1038b4aac4c9322fb6fc14b57e71ab02> /usr/lib/libtidy.A.dylib
    0x30f6a000 - 0x30f6efff  AggregateDictionary armv7  <622857a298f4300f888011527320fce2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
    0x3214a000 - 0x32160fff  DataAccessExpress armv7  <05a91911a3263f9eb0dfc04fbcb01e92> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
    0x335e6000 - 0x335e8fff  OAuth armv7  <219223002672398d96b9b7319a82c432> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OAuth.framework/OAuth
    0x387ff000 - 0x38820fff  libxslt.1.dylib armv7  <c5d2c1db0a203d26a577d6c231b3640d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
    0x2eb67000 - 0x2edaffff  JavaScriptCore armv7  <bf16837de28838d5b93cf3006ae44db2> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
    0x2ee60000 - 0x2ee64fff  MediaAccessibility armv7  <e0c6a7b66b3e3f998a4649a3fc144831> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaAccessibility.framework/MediaAccessibility
    0x31942000 - 0x31947fff  CertUI armv7  <5a3487647d1e35ad9a99c6268c13deba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CertUI.framework/CertUI
    0x37dc6000 - 0x37eb3fff  libiconv.2.dylib armv7  <3faa29f3ddf53187b51e155344592e1b> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
    0x385fe000 - 0x38613fff  libresolv.9.dylib armv7  <9d15aa14d7773e599e6cee134be9ebd0> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
    0x32fbd000 - 0x33038fff  ManagedConfiguration armv7  <0ab4df405afb356182c30add7a4752a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
    0x31da6000 - 0x31db0fff  CoreRecents armv7  <e6612bb8a57831e4a9848413334b5dbb> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRecents.framework/CoreRecents
    0x2d4a1000 - 0x2d7bafff  AudioToolbox armv7  <84c0f38107e93f0a8b5b5e27a42f971e> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
    0x32222000 - 0x32224fff  FTClientServices armv7  <29783c26358f3ccfa78d2e6ab760f386> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTClientServices.framework/FTClientServices
    0x3317d000 - 0x33251fff  Message armv7  <a2c5fd88d04b3879adf7d9b5aee355f7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Message.framework/Message
    0x31f7e000 - 0x31fb5fff  DataAccess armv7  <22e3bacb69b53385861a6e5562aa0161> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccess.framework/DataAccess
    0x2e372000 - 0x2e431fff  EventKit armv7  <7596bc6d267534c6860adce649ddb9ea> /System/Library/Frameworks/EventKit.framework/EventKit
    0x32f7e000 - 0x32f89fff  MailServices armv7  <81ef7a9141b036e68cf5ef26336e9ea8> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MailServices.framework/MailServices
    0x32efe000 - 0x32f37fff  MIME armv7  <a9180657590b3f108fb009d01d52d316> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MIME.framework/MIME
    0x3185a000 - 0x31935fff  Celestial armv7  <abf73e5caa3a3cdeb29020e899276823> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
    0x301ec000 - 0x30242fff  QuickLook armv7  <729e1946e10f334da6ce116596c5b238> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/QuickLook
    0x33256000 - 0x33258fff  MessageSupport armv7  <385d8cee193f31b6a87743c0c2bf290b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MessageSupport.framework/MessageSupport
    0x3835a000 - 0x3836efff  libmis.dylib armv7  <b8a7d92c3c823590a9edb7f8505ce49e> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
    0x335b5000 - 0x335bafff  Netrb armv7  <ef4e989f4867386a89b0e31458ae00ff> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Netrb.framework/Netrb
    0x34320000 - 0x34347fff  PersistentConnection armv7  <9d26150d24bf381db7e9941721ff30ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
    0x3219b000 - 0x3219ffff  DataMigration armv7  <81241cd0796c349cb62b15c0a412ba0d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
    0x32d01000 - 0x32d8efff  IMCore armv7  <0350b9aa0b0c3266bb2df8e59814bc86> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IMCore.framework/IMCore
    0x33039000 - 0x3303afff  Marco armv7  <7cb18ff3df8f3b90a61b81820fef86bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Marco.framework/Marco
    0x32225000 - 0x3224ffff  FTServices armv7  <f5f796c2d7e43f96a0627f31d60d497f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FTServices.framework/FTServices
    0x32be6000 - 0x32c1afff  IDS armv7  <4dc24a1de10d374ebbbeed9c883f6bd1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDS.framework/IDS
    0x321a4000 - 0x321a5fff  DiagnosticLogCollection armv7  <cb0e88a7ccb53fd69d15bd67e61524e0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiagnosticLogCollection.framework/DiagnosticLogCollection
    0x32c8a000 - 0x32c9bfff  IDSFoundation armv7  <4f334defe29b3e7bb19eb8769b720a49> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IDSFoundation.framework/IDSFoundation
    0x3289b000 - 0x32a46fff  GeoServices armv7  <5672c446f155346d9abe23bdaf0af406> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
    0x2cb99000 - 0x2cbc1fff  libAVFAudio.dylib armv7  <88a2ed6c453432868f8faa84748a861a> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/libAVFAudio.dylib
    0x2f063000 - 0x2f368fff  MediaToolbox armv7  <78e66ef0952f333290c553872415c3b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
    0x3498b000 - 0x349fffff  Quagga armv7  <ab3c7973d0983d5ea7f5a184de191437> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Quagga.framework/Quagga
    0x31759000 - 0x3175cfff  BTLEAudioController armv7  <597ddbf539b43ebaa6d7ff5632953b74> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BTLEAudioController.framework/BTLEAudioController
    0x335bb000 - 0x335c0fff  NetworkStatistics armv7  <f7b5f173637e36f185c1f276a4d47218> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NetworkStatistics.framework/NetworkStatistics
    0x3303b000 - 0x330b3fff  MediaControlSender armv7  <e33f516f11d832f7b9d04f6b219dcbe3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
    0x34ef2000 - 0x35013fff  StoreServices armv7  <a13847b6510b3f3d8d638a837f54be1f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
    0x31b6a000 - 0x31b6cfff  CoreAUC armv7  <2807429bc5a63ab9a72af73bfe61ea2d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreAUC.framework/CoreAUC
    0x330f2000 - 0x330fffff  MediaRemote armv7  <3533eef67ac735fcb4351f3d08c6e608> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
    0x3330f000 - 0x3331afff  MobileWiFi armv7  <2689696719d7358f87cd3526bd92fbea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
    0x316fb000 - 0x31701fff  AppleSRP armv7  <0960396e58323b29a09aeb9650829f5a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppleSRP.framework/AppleSRP
    0x31f24000 - 0x31f77fff  CoreUtils armv7  <512ab0cfcfab3cc9a43d46c8f66501bf> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreUtils.framework/CoreUtils
    0x31851000 - 0x31859fff  CaptiveNetwork armv7  <d986796d8aff37d3ad8b44c8582d23de> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
    0x321df000 - 0x321fcfff  EAP8021X armv7  <7f96a2f142b63883b62a4f38acb07467> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
    0x332b7000 - 0x332bafff  MobileInstallation armv7  <2dfdede78083348c848177887e6146e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iCalendar.framework/iCalendar
    0x335c1000 - 0x335e5fff  Notes armv7  <3c5c6f7efa3036b1a92597423db7cfa1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Notes.framework/Notes
    0x31b79000 - 0x31bcdfff  CoreDAV armv7  <0788bb75e05e3d14a2bb9b49a8274817> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDAV.framework/CoreDAV
    0x30e3b000 - 0x30e44fff  AOSNotification armv7  <4353ed1adf4a3242bba1f4150002c90a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Preferences.framework/Preferences
    0x3173c000 - 0x31758fff  AssistantServices armv7  <002609a7aff7399ebe5fb5159d9f4f54> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssistantServices.framework/AssistantServices
    0x35c7c000 - 0x35c99fff  VoiceServices armv7  <08b6a9b7921536c7888c669b181424d2> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VoiceServices.framework/VoiceServices
    0x332af000 - 0x332b6fff  MobileIcons armv7  <b3ed9b97170335049137718ad2bb196e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
    0x34b3f000 - 0x34bc4fff  SAObjects armv7  <aa0f8cd6c884394fa19eb667796481a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SAObjects.framework/SAObjects
    0x31248000 - 0x3125cfff  AirTraffic armv7  <2d6d0d9d60bf3ef1913563a92be77868> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
    0x36b92000 - 0x36bccfff  iTunesStore armv7  <ddda7723732b3961b6420cab2696a851> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
    0x32b73000 - 0x32b80fff  IAP armv7  <f1da475b6f6935f89eb6cd7012d190a3> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
    0x3335a000 - 0x334f6fff  MusicLibrary armv7  <2e10fc33910d356580646ca368abc9ea> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
    0x34a0b000 - 0x34ab0fff  Radio armv7  <a8e635434f3c303c976c3b40ed0e4bb6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Radio.framework/Radio
    0x32aed000 - 0x32b72fff  HomeSharing armv7  <713df79566ca3eefa37a569f7c721c71> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
    0x32ef1000 - 0x32efdfff  Librarian armv7  <0961437856a33402a87c1dfead65a092> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Librarian.framework/Librarian
    0x3583e000 - 0x35854fff  Ubiquity armv7  <602f20982e9f352b938a9681c8705bbc>  /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
    0x3513c000 - 0x354c5fff  KBLayouts_iPhone.dylib armv7  
    <4d4d99315ffd3d81b922831cc93061fc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/KBLayouts_iPhone.dylib
    0x2dfd7000 - 0x2dff1fff  libRIP.A.dylib armv7  <4f0d735448153b52a5e593a027eae891> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
    0x2dde8000 - 0x2ddf2fff  libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib armv7  <293a66777dfb3bf5a8877694abd4d76b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCMSBuiltin.A.dylib
    0x31e00000 - 0x31e1efff  CoreServicesInternal armv7  <3225429d38503c28a45844cf20da5118> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesInternal.framework/CoreServicesInternal
    0x37c66000 - 0x37c6dfff  libcupolicy.dylib armv7  <239ab9540e43378e88001f43f1d797ad> /usr/lib/libcupolicy.dylib
    0x2c8be000 - 0x2c9a6fff  RawCamera armv7  <5bcf485b4e0035cd8b766bac94d7aae9> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
    0x2fde3000 - 0x2feb2fff  GLEngine armv7  <1a7bfb99cd35369a94486639dd0b5a4b> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/GLEngine.bundle/GLEngine
    0x2ff0d000 - 0x30042fff  libGLProgrammability.dylib armv7  <c9d8578d9b7f3671b1957d2bdc259b08> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLProgrammability.dylib
    0x2febe000 - 0x2fec1fff  libCoreFSCache.dylib armv7  <9fd9d2449e4a34ad91b942043642f443> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreFSCache.dylib
    0x2c9bf000 - 0x2ca8cfff  IMGSGX535GLDriver armv7  <558572da96103a99aceeec351d64666b> /System/Library/Extensions/IMGSGX535GLDriver.bundle/IMGSGX535GLDriver
    0x32e6f000 - 0x32e71fff  IOAccelerator armv7  <6a375dbd238b31c580d0a59d29ffe7d6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOAccelerator.framework/IOAccelerator
    0x3269e000 - 0x326a4fff  libGPUSupportMercury.dylib armv7  <b1c56cc68679308f939c371925d6d522> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GPUSupport.framework/libGPUSupportMercury.dylib

    Extra Information:

    Application Stats:
    {
        "active_time_since_last_crash": 1323.81,
        "active_time_since_launch": 59.3068,
        "application_active": false,
        "application_in_foreground": false,
        "background_time_since_last_crash": 241.727,
        "background_time_since_launch": 3.44016,
        "launches_since_last_crash": 5,
        "sessions_since_last_crash": 11,
        "sessions_since_launch": 1
    }
```

I am not able to find line in this crash report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIGPIPE is usually a signal raised if something uses a pipe or socket which has been disconnected or broken by the other end and not been detected.

For unix, normally coders put a signal handler in place to ignore SIGPIPE as the default action is to exit or fault.

There was some discussion for iOS here which has a response from apple: http://www.badrit.com/blog/2010/11/30/ignore-sigpipe-signal-on-ios#.VQw1uHZpeiN

The simplest solution for you I think is to follow one of the suggestions on that link to add an ignore of that signal to your main.m as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  @autoreleasepool {
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);

    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```